# how to create Java and Gradle project in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

I installed IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Community Edition) in my computer.

I want to create new Java project and Gradle project.
But when I try to create new project, I can't find java or gradle options.
First pic is my IntelliJ and I want to be like second pic.
How can I solve this problem?

Thankyou.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAe5K.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeeNE.png

Answer (score 0):

They're hidden in plain sight :) Select Java in the language options (red solid box) and select Gradle in the build system options (yellow dashed box).

[image: annotated screenshot]

---

<sup>P.S.: This kind of looks like the [new UI](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-155/New-UI-Preview-for-JetBrains-IDEs) that's currently only available in [EAP](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/05/take-part-in-the-new-ui-preview-for-your-jetbrains-ide/).</sup>